# What is hashed in: git hash-object abc.txt?

Tags: git, sha1, git-hash

I have a file abc.txt whose file size is 3 and contains exact 3 characters `abc`. If I drag it into https://hexed.it, it is:

[image]

`git hash-object abc.txt` then produces `f2ba8f84ab5c1bce84a7b441cb1959cfc7093b7f`, whether with the `--no-filters` option or not.

However, if I go to any of the online SHA1 generators, the three characters `abc` gives `a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d`.

What is the content that `git hash-object` is using to compute the hash?

Comment: The hash is calculated from this content: `blob 3\0abc`, more specifically, `blob <file length><0-byte><file contents>`. It's explained in that link @evolutionxbox provided although I wouldn't say it's a clear explanation.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes. So it's the string "blob " followed by file size as a string followed by a byte of binary 0 and then the file contents.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it's rather difficult answer to understand